# requiring module by name is only supported in debugging mode and will break in production

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

i have a list of text and images, I get the name of the image from Firebase database and then concatenate the extracted name with a the path of the images' folder under my project: that's the code i used

```
var icon=  require ('path/'+item.image+'.png')

        return (
            ...
                    <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                           source={icon}/>
```

**The images are displayed but i have warnings as much as i have images in the list** 
i read somewhere this

> REQUIRE('IMAGE!...') NO LONGER SUPPORTED
>
> Support for require('image!…'), which has been deprecated for a long
>   time, is now removed. If you are still loading images that way in your
>   apps, make sure to check the documentation for alternatives.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit question being asked, so I will assume you're asking "what does this error mean?" and "what, if anything, should I do to make it go away?".

The `require('image!...')` is the (really) old way of using images in React Native. But I suspect your issue here is that you're building the image name dynamically.

See the [React Native docs on images](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html):

> In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : 
require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

So don't build your image name dynamically.

Yes, I feel your pain for having to write a switch-case for all countries of the world...

Comment: Thank you .. this solution worked perfectly fine although i had to make a massive switch case just like you said